# Why is my project un-parseable?

Tags: android

```
11-19 15:13:55.955: W/PackageManager(2096): verifying app can be installed or not
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096): /data/app/vmdl2068695449.tmp
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to integer: type=0x3
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInteger(TypedArray.java:367)
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:856)
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:444)
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:7689)
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$1500(PackageManagerService.java:174)
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$6.run(PackageManagerService.java:6222)
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-19 15:13:56.020: W/PackageParser(2096):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION

What is the problem and how do I solve this?

Comment: Could you post the code around line 367, please

Comment: +1. The whole method embedding the line 367 of TypedArray.java.

Comment: @OfekRon It could be possible that it isn't supported in the sdk you are using? Try to target a higher SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved - The problem was that i entered a non-integer value to the version code in the menisfest file.

Answer (score -2):

I guess this is the problem:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to integer: type=0x3
```

and it occurs here:

```
TypedArray.java (line 367)
```

Comment: but this is Android's code in Android core library so that is really not helpfull